# Improving EC2 ping times from home

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, hamachi

I've been trying to run a gaming machine in EC2 following the excellent blog post by Larry Land [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839785/is-media-foundation-supported-on-windows-2012-64-bit-server).  The problem I have is latency from my home to my nearest AWS region.  I get a ping of around 35ms, and I'm looking to improve on that.  Is there anything I can do?  I'm using Steam in-home streaming over a Hamachi VPN, on Windows Server 2012.

My internet connection is roughly 120Mbps down and 35Mbps up, and there's nothing I can do to improve on that sadly.

Comment: I originally incorrectly posted this on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009905/improving-ec2-ping-times-from-home), where @datasage responded with some helpful tips.

Answer (score 1):

The latency between you and your EC2 instance is decided by three factors. The first is the speed of light - this is not something you can do anything about.

The second is the delay caused by the last mile access, and depends on what kind of technology is used. Cable? Ethernet? (See three)

The third is the path your packets take over the network. This is something you MIGHT be able to do something about, but most likeley it would require you to switch to a different service provider with better routing towards the EC2 instance.